# [SOLVED] Rviz 2D Nav Goal/Pose Estimate do not work

Tags: ros, rviz, 2d-nav-goal, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

We've seem to run into a problem just earlier this week. For the past 8 months we were able to send 2d nav goals and set the 2d initial pose using Rviz perfectly fine. We are usin ROS Fuerte. Just earlier this week, we are not able to do this anymore at all.
When I send the 2d nav goal, it's not getting published to the rostopic and hence, nothing seems to happen. I cannot even set the initial 2d pose estimate.
We've tried reinstalling the visualization packages and still no luck at all.

Could anyone please suggest any solutions?
Many thanks!

EDIT: We've solved the issue. Turns out the ROS_HOSTNAME on the workstation was incorrect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160601/%5Bsolved%5D-rviz-2d-nav-goal/pose-estimate-do-not-work/) by [aviprobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/6004/aviprobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2014-05-05**:
Check whether correct topics are set for Rviz tools. Goto Panel -> Tool properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Adding the comptuername to the /etc/hosts on both client and server solves many problems.

;-)

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1